# Updating order WooCommerce API PHP CURL

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl, woocommerce

I'm developing a web application for my co-workers, so they'll have an iPad with an application, to package our orders.

Whole app is almost finished, one of the last steps is to change order status from **processing** to **completed**.

What I'm doing:

Get current order ID, then change status with curl or API. What happens is very strange, I get JSON data back, and the completed_at time updated, but status is still processing.

Below you will see my code:

```
$data = array("status" => "completed");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$username = 'XXX'; // Add your own Consumer Key here
$password = 'XXX'; // Add your own Consumer Secret here

$ch = curl_init('https://www.deallerleukste.nl/wc-api/v2/orders/5764?consumer_key='.$username.'&consumer_secret='.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
```

Anyone who sees what I'm doing wrong? Please help!

Regards,

Jelmer

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this code

```
$data='{  "order": {    "status": "completed"  }}';
```

or

Dynamically

```
$data=json_encode( array( 'order' => array( 'status' => $status)));
```

in $status you can pass the status u want.

Answer (score 0):

I see it is a quite old post, but today I ran into the same problem, so maybe it is useful.

You have to use PUT instead of POST here:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

and data should be a valid JSON in this format:

`$data='{"status": "completed"}';`